# Xamarin unit test won't load to simulator or phone: "Cannot register two managed types ... with the same native name ('AppDelegate')."

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've created a new Unit Test project in my Xamarin app using the "Unit Test App (iOS)" template per the instructions [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/touch.unit/).

Some of the code I need to test is located in my native iOS client project, so I added a reference to it in the test project and tried to run it. I get a build error that makes sense, after a fashion:

> Could not register the assembly 'myclient.iOS': error MT4118: Cannot register two managed types ('myclient.iOS.AppDelegate, myclient.iOS' and 'myclient.Specification.AppDelegate, myclient.Specification') with the same native name ('AppDelegate').

It makes sense because the AppDelegate classes in both cases are annotated the same way: [Register("AppDelegate")]. Manually changing the annotation on the unittest project causes it not to be runnable on the sim or a device.

My question: Is there a way to build and run a Unit Test fixture that tests code in a native iOS client library?

Comment: A Xamarin.iOS-based library yes, an iOS application, no. If the code you are testing needs iOS APIs, then move it to a iOS library and use a platform application runner to test it (NUnitLite for Devices, NUnit for Devices, XUnit for Devices, etc..). If the code does not reference any iOS APIs, then move it to a normal library and reference it in a std. N|XUnit project.

Comment: Hi Sushi, if you'll copy your comment into an answer I'll mark it as the solution. I arrived there on my own but you should get the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Xamarin.iOS-based library yes, an iOS application, no.

If the code you are testing needs iOS APIs but not **UI** controls, then move that code to a iOS library and use a *platform application runner* to test it (NUnitLite for Devices, NUnit for Devices, XUnit for Devices, etc..).

- [`Xamarin.iOS` Unit Testing](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/touch.unit/)

#### Alternatives to Xamarin's NUnitLite:

- [xUnit.net Runners for Devices](https://github.com/xunit/devices.xunit)
- [NUnit test runners for Xamarin and mobile devices](https://github.com/nunit/nunit.xamarin)

If the code does not reference any iOS APIs, then move it to a normal library and reference it in a standard N|XUnit project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your UI in native library there is [Xamarin.UITest](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/intro-to-uitest/) framework which is the Automation Library that allows the NUnit tests to execute on Android and iOS devices.

The tests interact with the user interface just as a user would, enter text, tapping buttons, and performing gestures more info [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/introduction-to-test-cloud/#The_Anatomy_of_the_Test_Cloud_Framework)